# Need to delete all the files in a folder except the file which contains current datetime in the file name using sql job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-job

I have a text file in the name of **BankDetails_09302014_153054.txt** in one folder. I need to create a  SQL job which will delete old files except current datetime file. (ie **BankDetails_10012014_103104.txt**). This sql job need to be execute on daily basis. Kindly give me some suggestions to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered here on how to get your Creation and modifieddate of a file

- [Source 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic494395-149-1.aspx)
- [Source 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic494395-149-1.aspx)
- [Source 3](http://www.justskins.com/forums/find-file-size-last-92750.html)

Once you get your respective date you can compare and delete. Hope this helps

Comment: I am expecting something related to xp_cmdshell. Using this one we can delete the required files. But I am stuck with the place to delete the file based on filename date.

Comment: Oic. Have not perform the operation before. But it seems to me if i can return the dates then we can compare and delete. I found an interesting article                                   Here  = >   http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-file-from-sql-server-xp-cmdshell-ole-automation-procedures.aspx  on how to delete the files with xp_cmdshell . Perhaps may b will try in my free time. Thought it might helps.